# Samba domain is not connecting to windows 10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

We're currently in the process of upgrading our workstations from Windows 7 to Windows 10. We've been running into some issues with logging into our domain from the Windows 10 machines.

The issues seem to be occurring when dealing with a workstation that wasn't upgraded from Windows 7, but instead just started out on Windows 10. When we upgrade from 7 and then try to login, it works just fine.

When we have a computer that started out on Windows 10 and wasn't upgraded, we're able to join it to the domain after adding 2 registry keys (we get the Welcome to domain! message and all), but then when we attempt to login with a domain username/password, we get the following error message:

"We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential."

In addition to this, today we created a new domain user that was unable to log in. On the same workstation running Windows 10 it will allow an old domain user to log in just fine, but won't allow the new domain user to log in. The same error message as above is displayed when facing this issue.

We've tried disabling IPv6, enabled SMB1.0, looked extensively into DNS settings and tried every possibility there, but are just having no luck with figuring this out.

I figured I'd check and see if any of you have had any experience with this or a similar issue. Any info you can provide would be appreciated!

The version of samba were on is 4.7.6 when we set the server max protocol to NT1 we were able to log into the users however we were not able to connect to some of the other drives.

Please help, 
Thanks.